# Save value from text area in cookie and then reload page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have some text area and a table which I want to change after key pressed in text area.

```
$("#fioFilter").keydown(function(e){
    $.cookie("fioFilter",$("#fioFilter").val());
});
$("#fioFilter").keyup(function(e){
    window.location.reload();
});
```

This is my solution. This doesn't works as I want. If I hold key pressed some time it saves in cookies and then reloads. But if I just press one time on key. It reloads and returns old value. What's the problem?
http://jsfiddle.net/d6fpfzsu/

Comment: `Uncaught exception: TypeError: '$.cookie' is not a function`

Comment: Thanx to rGraham fiddle works fine now

Comment: But my problem is stil actual. Try to  hold key some time, then it will save cookie. And try just one time press key. It will return old value.

Comment: Oddly, if you set the cookie value to a static value, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/tt2tyuo3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working on Opera 12.17 on Windows XP

This is my solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var time;
    if($.cookie('fioFilter')!=null)
    {
        $("#fioFilter").focus().text($.cookie('fioFilter'));
    }
    $("#fioFilter").keyup(function(e){
        clearTimeout(time);
        $.cookie("fioFilter",$("#fioFilter").val());
        time=setTimeout(function(){$("#fioFilter").change();},500);
    });
    $("#fioFilter").change(function(e){
        window.location.reload();
    });
});
```

I got it working by changing from `keydown` to `keyup`.

The reload is done on `change` event, which is triggered after 500ms or when the `<textarea>` loses focus.
Setting the focus **before** the value ensures the prompt stays at the end.
This is a "fix" for chrome only.

If there is a cookie set, it will focus the element.

You can check the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/w6hk7w6b/5/

**Note**

I know I can just set a `var` and save the selector.

I won't do it for simplicity (and laziness).

Comment: Seems that in doesn't reloads.

Comment: Oh, its reloads but some time later. Gonna read change doc. Thanx, man

Comment: The `change` event is handled differently in each browser, but it's the best bet. I was writing the edit when you commented.

Comment: The change event is fired on lost focus for "text" elements, insted is fired immediately for checkboxes and radiobuttons

Comment: In Crome and firefox it reloads only when I click some other place. Loose focus, right Luca, so it doesn't work propprely still.

Comment: Great! Now I should find a way to put cursor in end of page after reload.

Comment: What browser it doesn't go to the end? You can do that by setting the selection range to be the value length+1.

Comment: The way to solve this is by changing the order that you set the values. If you set the `focus` then the `text`, it will be fine but I can't post a working fiddle because I get the error `{"error": "Please use POST request"}`.